# Poisson Distribution: Proof of successive probabilities

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I am a bit stuck on the following question and need some help with the following question:

"For a certain experiment, the Poisson distribution with parameter $λ = m$ has been assigned. Show that a most probable outcome for the experiment is the integer value $k$ such that $m − 1 ≤ k ≤ m$. Under what conditions will there be two most probable values? Hint: Consider the ratio of successive probabilities."

The solution says that $$\frac{P(\text{outcome is } j+1)}{P(\text{outcome is } j)} = \frac{\frac{m^{j+1}e^{-m}}{(j+1)!}}{\frac{m^je^{-m}}{j!}} = \frac{m}{j+1}$$

I'm not quite sure how it came up with this, would someone mind explaining please ?

Thank you

Comment: Note the proper use of \text{} in MathJax, as in my edit to the question. $\qquad$

Comment: Do you know that $\Pr(\text{outcome is }j) = \dfrac{m^j e^{-m}}{j!}$? $\qquad$

Comment: No I will keep in mind the text command. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelHardy actually sorry I didn't exactly see the 2nd command properly and just viewed it now. I wasn't told that the outcome $\text{Pr}(\text{outcome is } j) = \frac{m^{j}e^{-m}}{j!}$ which is what I find really puzzling. So I guess that is an assumption made ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I will go out on a bit of a limb and guess that you are familiar with the fact that $$\Pr(\text{outcome is }j) = \frac{m^j e^{-m}}{j!}$$ (mainly because it doesn't make sense to work on problems involving the Poisson distribution unless you know that), and that the part you're having trouble with is showing that
$$
\frac{\left(\dfrac{m^{j+1}e^{-m}}{(j+1)!}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{m^je^{-m}}{j!}\right)} = \frac{m}{j+1}.
$$

We have
$$
\frac{\left(\dfrac{m^{j+1}e^{-m}}{(j+1)!}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{m^je^{-m}}{j!}\right)} = \frac{m^{j+1} e^{-m}}{(j+1)!}\cdot\frac{j!}{m^j e^{-m}} = \frac{m\cdot 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots j}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots j\cdot(j+1)} = \frac m {j+1}.
$$

Comment: actually sorry I didn't exactly see the 2nd command properly and just viewed it now. I wasn't told that the outcome $\text{Pr}(\text{outcome is } j) = \frac{m^{j}e^{-m}}{j!}$ which is what I find really puzzling. So I guess that is an assumption made ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls : That's the definition of the Poisson distribution. $\qquad$

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted what you meant but yes, I do know that definition. Thank you